# How to detect when textures are destroyed

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

How do i detect when my textures are destroyed on android?
My Renderer class for my GLSurfaceView currently looks like this:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    nativeLibrary.drawFrame();
}
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) 
{
    if (reload)
    {
        library.glRecreate(); //this method reloads destroyed textures
    }
    else
    {
        nativeLibrary.init(width, height)); //this method initializes my game
        reload = true;
    }
}
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) 
{
}
```

The problem is that doesn't always work. When i press the home button from my game and then start it again, it works like a charm. But when i lock the device, and then unlock it again, all textures are just black. Everything seems to reset when I lock it too (my game always comes back in the main menu). When I quit the game using the home button, and do a lock/unlock after that, the game doesn't reset.

Comment: Maybe an important detail: it DID work before. Back then i created my GLSurfaceView manually, now i load it through xml.

Comment: And if you go back to creating it manually, does it work again? Most, if not all, examples create the GLSurfaceView in code. I think I actually tried creating it from XML once, don't recall why it failed.

Comment: The problem was somewhere else. The screen orientation is reverted back to portrait when locking the screen. This actually kills the app (as onDestroy is called), but somehow android fails to remember that, and just onResumes my game when unlocking the screen. When calling System.exit(0); in onDestroy, the game is just gone when unlocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing OpenGL on Android, I *highly* recommend that you watch [these](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic) [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk) Google I/O talks by Chris Pruett, Android advocate, who wrote the open-source game [Replica Island](http://www.replicaisland.net/).

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk#t=23m57s) he talks about the exact problem you're seeing. Long story short: you don't detect when your textures (and buffers) are destroyed, but you detect when they need to be recreated. And this is exactly what the [`onSurfaceCreated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onSurfaceCreated%28javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10,%20javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig%29) callback is for:

> Since this method is called at the beginning of rendering, as well as every time the EGL context is lost, this method is a convenient place to put code to create resources that need to be created when the rendering starts, and that need to be recreated when the EGL context is lost. Textures are an example of a resource that you might want to create here.

Comment: Chris has definitely made it a lot simpler to write Games for Android.  Love his work.

Comment: It just doesn't work! When I do an unlock of my screen, the textures are black anyway, even when i moved all loading stuff to onSurfaceCreated

Comment: Are you also recreating your texture objects (i.e. `glGenTextures`) and taking into account that their IDs might not be the same?

Comment: I did take that into account. It does work when another activity comes on top of mine, and then goes away again. In that case the textures just reload fine. The problem is when locking/unlocking the screen.

Comment: If you're properly reloading everything from scratch, it shouldn't be any different from a cold start, right? I don't see how it could still go wrong. Did you check the result of `glGetError`? Most easily done by calling `glSurfaceView.setDebugFlags(DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR);` right after creating your `GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: My DDMS does not report anything.. And a cold start (calling init instead of reload) just yields the same result.